# Processing: manipulate variables by string names

Tags: java, variables, reference, text-files, processing

I am importing a .txt file to use to run parts of my program.  A certain part needs to manipulate boolean variables.  However, I am using loadStrings() to interpret the text into Strings, with the individual lines called lines[].  I have a variable's name as a String and must reference the variable itself.  Unfortunately, I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

```
boolean choice1 = false;

//  lines[counter+2] is "choice1"
if (lines[counter+2] = false) {
    println("statement is false");
    counter += 4;
  }
```

Obviously, the above statement doesn't work, nor does:

```
if (boolean(lines[counter+2]) = false) {
```

as it errors.
Also,

```
if (boolean(lines[counter+2]) == false) {
```

is not a possible solution as any word other than "true" when used in boolean() is false, so the above gives a false positive (pardon the pun).

If there is a solution to the same problem in java coding, I would be happy to see that as well.

P.S.  If you have a solution, is there a way to not just reference the variable by its name, but also to change it?  For example:

```
boolean(lines[counter+2]) = false;
```

or

```
lines[counter+2] = false;
```

obviously, the above are incorrect, but that idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

You could use a `HashMap` of `String` values to `Boolean` values though:

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
variableMap.put("myVariable", true); //set the value
boolean check = variableMap.get("myVariable"); //get the value
println(check);
variableMap.put("myVariable", false); //change the value
boolean checkAgain = variableMap.get("myVariable"); //get the new value
println(checkAgain);
```

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/HashMap.html).